# Mutation of captured var in actor isolated context

Tags: swift, actor

I encountered an issue with an actor which causes a compiler error which in my humble opinion should compile fine:

```
actor TestActor<Event> {
    private let _send: (isolated TestActor, Event) -> Void
    
    init(transform: @escaping @Sendable (Event) -> () async -> Void) {
        var a: [UUID: Task<Void, Never>] = [:]
        
        _send = { actor, event in
            actor.assertIsolated()
            let id = UUID()
            a[id] = Task {
                actor.assertIsolated()
                let f = transform(event)
                await f()
                actor.assertIsolated()
                a[id] = nil // <= Mutation of captured var 'a' in concurrently-executing code
            }
        }
    }

    func send(event: Event) {
        _send(self, event)
    }
}
```

The implementation probably deserves some clarification:

The actor has a closure `_send` as member. In order to make the closure bind to an isolated context, it has an `isolated` parameter.

I made the following assumption:

When the closure will be called it is isolated to the parameter `actor` which is actually `self`.

The initialiser creates a local var of type dictionary.

The local var will be captured in the closure. Since the closure is isolated to its isolated parameter `actor` - which is actually `self` - it should be safe to make mutations to the captured var `a` within it, even when multiple closures interleave.
There "might" be a race condition (which is not harmful in this implementation) - but there should be no data race.

Actually, the compiler will not complain mutating the captured variable `a` within the closure. However, it will complain when mutating it in the task created in the closure.

However, my understanding is, that a (non-detached) Tasks will inherit the actor's context, i.e. that of the isolated parameter `actor` (which is `self`). So within the task, it should again be OK to mutate the captured variable `a`.

I tried to confirm my assumptions with the added asserts. The asserts actually do not fail during runtime. Nonetheless, the compiler issues an error when I try to mutate the captured variable `a` when running in the isolated context of `actor` (which is `self`).

Note: if the actor uses a *member* `a` (instead of the *captured* var) - the compiler will not complain!

Running the code with the offending line commented out, the asserts will not fire.

**Possibly related:**
https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/63773

**Edit**

This is the version where the captured var `a` is replaced with a member:

```
actor TestActor<Event> {
    private let _send: (isolated TestActor, Event) -> Void
    private var a: [UUID: Task<Void, Never>] = [:]

    init(transform: @escaping @Sendable (Event) -> () async -> Void) {
        _send = { actor, event in
            actor.assertIsolated()
            let id = UUID()
            actor.a[id] = Task {
                actor.assertIsolated()
                let f = transform(event)
                await f()
                actor.assertIsolated()
                actor.a[id] = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func send(event: Event) {
        _send(self, event)
    }
}
```

This compiles without errors or warnings with a standard Package for Swift 5.9 without any extra flags.

**Edit:**
Added `@Sendable` to the transform function.

Comment: "if the actor uses a member a (instead of the captured var) - the compiler will not complain!" Can you show the code? With strict concurrency, it still gives me an error *and* a warning.

Comment: @Sweeper Sure! I edited the question and added the version using a member `a` instead of the captured one. I'm currently using a Package without setting extra flags.